# JFile::makeSafe does not convert file name

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, file-upload

I need to rename and save a file upload when saving an item in a custom component.
The problem is that the JFile::makeSafe function seems like is not converting the filename as you can see below.

So I have overridden the save function in the models/test.php like this :

```
  public function save($data) {
    JRequest::checkToken() or die('Invalid Token');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $date = JFactory::getDate()->format('Y-m-d h:m:s');

    if (empty($data['created'])) {
      $data['created'] = $date;
    }

    if (!empty($data['file'])) {
      $data['file'] = JFile::makeSafe($data['file']);
      $src = $data['file'];
      $dest = JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/uploads/' . $data['client_id'] . '/' . $data['id'] . '_' . $data['file'];

      if (strtolower(JFile::getExt($data['file'])) == 'doc' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($data['file'])) == 'docx') {
        JLog::add('File Destination: ' . $dest, JLog::DEBUG, 'com_test-save item');
        if (JFile::upload($src, $dest)) {

        }
      }
      }
      JLog::add('Data to save: ' . print_r($data, TRUE), JLog::DEBUG, 'com_test-save item');
    }

    return parent::save($data);
  }
```

The log :

```
2018-07-20T09:02:38+00:00       DEBUG 127.0.0.1 com_testt-saveitem   Filename before JFile::makeSafe : My FILE TO UPLOAD.docx
2018-07-20T09:02:38+00:00       DEBUG 127.0.0.1 com_test-saveitem   Filename AFTER JFile::makeSafe : My FILE TO UPLOAD.docx
2018-07-20T09:02:38+00:00       DEBUG 127.0.0.1 com_test-saveitem   File Destination: /Projects/myProjects/joomla/administrator/components/com_test/uploads/240/2_My FILE TO UPLOAD.docx
2018-07-20T09:02:38+00:00       DEBUG 127.0.0.1 com_test-saveitem   Data to save: Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [title] => test
    [alias] => test
    [catid] => 0
    [client_id] => 240
    [published] => 0
    [created] => 2018-07-20 06:07:43
    [file] => My FILE TO UPLOAD.docx
    [tags] => 
)
```

And when I save the item, I get the following warning :

```
    Warning
    Warning: Failed to move file: My FILE TO UPLOAD.docx to /Projects/myProjects/joomla/administrator/components/com_test/uploads/240/2_My FILE TO UPLOAD.docx
```

The models/forms/test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <field name="id" type="text" default="0" label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_LABEL"
           readonly="true" class="readonly"
           description="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_DESC"/>
    <field name="title" type="text" class="inputbox"
           size="40" label="JGLOBAL_TITLE"
           description="COM_TEST_FIELD_TITLE_DESC" required="true" />
    <field name="alias" type="text" class="inputbox"
           size="40" label="JFIELD_ALIAS_LABEL"
           description="COM_TEST_FIELD_ALIAS_DESC" />
    <field name="access" type="accesslevel" label="JFIELD_ACCESS_LABEL"
           description="JFIELD_ACCESS_DESC" class="span12 small" size="1" />
    <field name="catid" type="category" extension="com_test" class="inputbox" default="" label="COM_TEST_FIELD_CATID_LABEL" 
           description="COM_TEST_FIELD_CATID_DESC">
      <option value="0">JOPTION_SELECT_CATEGORY</option>
    </field>
    <field name="client_id" type="user"
           label="COM_TEST_USER"
           description="COM_TEST_USER_DESC"
           required="true" />
    <field name="published" type="list" label="JSTATUS" description="JFIELD_PUBLISHED_DESC" class="inputbox small" size="1" default="1" >
      <option value="1">JPUBLISHED</option>
      <option value="0">JUNPUBLISHED</option>
      <option value="2">JARCHIVED</option>
      <option value="-2">JTRASHED</option>
    </field>
    <field
      name="cache_handler" type="cachehandler" default="" label="COM_TEST_FIELD_CACHE_HANDLER_LABEL"
      description="COM_TEST_FIELD_CACHE_HANDLER_DESC" filter="word">
      <field name="catid" type="category" extension="com_test"
             label="JCATEGORY" description="COM_TEST_FIELD_CATEGORY_DESC"
             class="inputbox"
      >
      </field>
    </field>
    <field
      name="created" 
      type="calendar" 
      label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_LABEL"
      description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_DESC"
      translateformat="true"
      showtime="true"
      size="22"
      filter="user_utc" />
      <field name="file" type="file" label="Enter some text" description="Choose an image from your computer with maximum 100KB" 
             size="40" accept=".doc, .docx" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not becuase you're appending `$data['id']` to the file name in the destination?

Comment: Yes,  If you take a look to the JLog commands there is on just before the JFile::makeSafe and one right after it and  print exactly the same output. But just to be sure I tried to remove the $data['id'] from the destination with exactly the same result.

Comment: You might like to DRY out the one line to be: `if (in_array(strtolower(JFile::getExt($data['file'])), ['doc', 'docx'])) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `JFile::makeSafe()` method doesn't do the conversion that I thought it did. I thought that it would remove spaces from the filename as well.

The description in the Joomla docs is not very clear.

> Description
>   Makes file name safe to use.

So I used `strtolower()` and `str_replace()` to modify the filename.

Comment: If your question is resolved, please accept your own answer so that the system stops bumping it.